# Efficient vehicle routing for transfer of packages

Tags: excel, routes

I have a warehouse and three distribution and receiving locations. I know the distances between each of them in relation to each other. Each location has a varying amount of standard size packages but of varying weight.

I have three vehicles, one that carries 30 packages or 1100lbs, one that carries 20 packages or 700lbs, and one that carries 15 packages or 500lbs.

I am trying to make a spreadsheet that can enter in the packages and their weights I have to send to each location and a how many I need to bring in and have it automatically calculate which vehicle or combination to use and which route in the most efficient manner.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Geno

Comment: That's a big ask without showing what you have tried and where its not working!  Have you looked at commercially available scheduling programs?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can start with this basic model using the solver and expand it with the detail you want to include. Shown the calculation by cell, row or column...

[image]