# Rearrange equations

Tags: excel, vba

For instance a simple equation is

```
F = m * a
```

And I have in my excel sheet

[image]

So in here I have not entered `m`
Would it be possible to rearrange the equation to calculate for `m`

```
m = F / a
```

- Does excel have a built in facility to do this?
- Can VBA do this?
- Any other way to achieve this incase the above 2 are not possible?

So basically If I leave any one of the variable cells blank and fill in the other two, I would like the result for the 3rd variable.

Comment: Simple solution - use 3 columns, each with different missing variable, with appropriate formula. Lock the cell with formula so the users cannot overwrite it. (Or use VBA, if you want only 1 column.)

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B4")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Application.Count(Range("B2:B4")) = 2 Then
            If IsEmpty(Range("B2")) Then
                Range("B2") = Range("B3").Value2 * Range("B4").Value2
            ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("B3")) Then
                Range("B3") = Range("B2").Value2 / Range("B4").Value2
            Else
                Range("B4") = Range("B2").Value2 / Range("B3").Value2
            End If

            Range("B2").NumberFormat = "0 \N"
            Range("B3").NumberFormat = "0.0 \k\g"
            Range("B4").NumberFormat = "0 \m\/\s\²"
        End If
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you code it that it picks up the formula from the sheet and solves it? for example C=SQRT(Gamma / R * T)...

Comment: @SolarMike I guess excel had a hidden feature `EVALUATE` to do what you are asking for, but I don't think it can rearrange. https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html

Comment: @MiguelSanchez "had" is incorrect, it still exists and works well, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315486/4961700

Comment: @SolarMike yes I tested it out it still works, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a if() statement:

```
=if(b3="",b2/B4,if(b2="",B3*b4,if(b4="",b2/b3,"Check")))
```

Not put any error checking such as checking for numbers in any two cells etc...

[image]

Comment: Can this be done as a generic function so that it can be applied to other equations as well, I mean like `Power = Torque * Speed` I mean can a generic VBA function be made for this?

Comment: That works for any similar formula as is, V=IR etc. **BUT** as soon as the formula changes you will have to edit it appropriately. Easy enough... My HP 24SX has a "solver" which you enter the equation and the values, then tell it to solve for ANY of the variables... no changing the equation around... Putting that into vba will be fun - good luck.

Comment: Excel has an inbuilt Solver addin can that achieve this?

Comment: @MiguelSanchez you should open the solver and have a go... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652049/4961700  , but you will still need to swap between the formulae to use to solve each different case and, yes, that is possible - use the if() statement...

Comment: Python engines like `SymPy` have rearrange equation inbuilt into them, eg for `V=IR` we can tell it to solve for I and it will do the rearrange and provide `I=V/R` Is there a similar feature in Excel without us writing `IF()` statements?