# Crew members rotation board at work using excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

At work, we assigned some tasks that we have to do. We have two main shifts, the AM and the PM.
In the AM, one crew member is assigned to check the equipment,
another one is assigned filling up the equipment and the third one is assigned the watch over the equipment.

The PM one crew member is assigned to check the equipment, and the second one is assigned the watch over the equipment.

Each shift has about 5 crew members. Open 7 days a week.

Now, I am trying to automate the assignments so that crew members don't get assigned to do one task twice during their 5 days of work.

Is there a way of doing such a thing using excel if number of crew members is know?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do darned near everything in Excel. You'll have to be a LOT more specific about how your workbook is set up and what you are wanting to do for more of an answer though.

Comment: Use the solver, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652049/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Try working from this, you will need to expand for assistants, but the method is clear...

[image]