# Looking to identify a "classic" problem and identify availble algorithms to solve it

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a problem that I'm sure is a classic but I cant find the name of this problem. Since I am very bad at formalizing with mathematical formulas, here is a picture and a written explanation.

[image: Graphical representation]

I have a product that is stored in n different warehouses W (on the left of the graph). I have stores S that can receive up to a given a quantity of this product (note capacity on the graph). I also have a "rubbish" that can handle the extra amount of products if the number of products in the warehouse exceed the capacity of the stores.

I have costs of distributing a single unit of the product from each warehouse to each store and also to rubish C(Wn,Sm) in blue for warehouse W1 in the graph I didnt add all the other C so that it is still readable.

I need to distribute all the products in the warehouse to all the stores (+ rubish eventually) while minimizing the cost (or maximising the gain if C is the price paid by store S to be supplied from warehouse W).

What is this problem called ? Is it NP complete ? What algorithm can solve it ? My first thought was Hungarian algorithm of assignment optimal but I found it dead end because that would be the best assignment from single W to single S.

When C is a matrix of all ones, I can find a solution using the max flow algorithm. But when C is different for each edge, I'm stuck.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The excel Solver set up like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652049/4961700

Comment: What is this problem called? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this?  What's the motivation?  Please avoid salutations like "Thanks" etc.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78019883/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4865574/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly called a Transport or Network Model, which you can find in tomes such as Management Science Modelling by Albright & Winston.

So did this just to show:

[image]

Variations include trying to minimise the cost of rubbish - then W3 supplies S1:S3.
You could have other criteria such as each W must use a minimum of some percentage of its capacity as in be "fair" to all suppliers...

Comment: just tried that on libreoffice so that would be the min cost flow problem as commented by @Stef and an algorithm to solve it the simplexe

Comment: So the names might vary ( many models or problems are minimum cost...) but you should see the Simplex LP selected as the solving method in the settings I show for the Solver.